# CQL no viable alternative at input '(' error

Tags: cassandra, cql, database, nosql

I have a issue with my CQL and cassandra is giving me `no viable alternative at input '(' (...WHERE id = ? if [(]...)` error message. I think there is a problem with my statement.

```
UPDATE <TABLE> USING TTL 300 
  SET <attribute1> = 13381990-735b-11e5-9bed-2ae6d3dfc201
  WHERE <attribute2> = dfa2efb0-7247-11e5-a9e5-0242ac110003 
    IF (<attribute1> = null OR <attribute1> = 13381990-735b-11e5-9bed-2ae6d3dfc201) AND <attribute3> = 0;
```

Any idea were the problem is in the statement about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to have your complete table structure, so to test your statement I made a couple of educated guesses.

With this table:

```
CREATE TABLE lwtTest (attribute1 timeuuid, attribute2 timeuuid PRIMARY KEY, attribute3 int);
```

This statement works, as long as I don't add the lightweight transaction on the end:

```
UPDATE lwttest USING TTL 300 SET attribute1=13381990-735b-11e5-9bed-2ae6d3dfc201 
WHERE attribute2=dfa2efb0-7247-11e5-a9e5-0242ac110003;
```

Your lightweight transaction...

```
IF (attribute1=null OR attribute1=13381990-735b-11e5-9bed-2ae6d3dfc201) AND attribute3 = 0;
```

...has a few issues.

- "null" in Cassandra is not similar (at all) to its RDBMS counterpart.  Not every row needs to have a value for every column.  Those CQL rows without values for certain column values in a table will show "null."  But you cannot query by "null" since it isn't really there.
- The OR keyword does not exist in CQL.
- You cannot use extra parenthesis to separate conditions in your WHERE clause or your lightweight transaction.

Bearing those points in mind, the following UPDATE and lightweight transaction runs without error:

```
UPDATE lwttest USING TTL 300 SET attribute1=13381990-735b-11e5-9bed-2ae6d3dfc201 
WHERE attribute2=dfa2efb0-7247-11e5-a9e5-0242ac110003
IF attribute1=13381990-735b-11e5-9bed-2ae6d3dfc201 AND attribute3=0;

 [applied]
-----------
     False
```

Comment: Great answer! Therefore I haven't found a statements that have a parenthesis and OR condition at the documents.

Comment: The information about 'null' is also very helpful and good to know because in the cql shell you see actually the value 'null'.